# Ruby module optimization

Tags: ruby, optimization, refactoring

I'm new to ruby, but have great experience with other languages such as php, python, javascript etc.

I have been writing this module with implementation of blend modes in ruby, to get used to the language. However I think there could be made a lot of optimization and automation. I've been looking around in the docs, but it's really hard to find what I'm looking for, as I don't know the excat technical terms for the techniques I want to use.

Here's a small portion of my module:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
    def union(b, s)
        return b + s - (b * s)
    end

    def color_composite(cb, ab, cs, as, fnc)
        return ((1 - as) * ab * cb) + ((1- ab) * as * cs) + (ab * as * fnc)
    end

    def multiply_channel(cb, cs)
        return cb * cs / 255
    end
    #MULTIPLY
    def multiply(top, bottom)
        assert_type top, :Color
        assert_type bottom, :Color

        red = color_composite(bottom.red, bottom.alpha, top.red, top.alpha, multiply_channel(bottom.red, top.red));
        green = color_composite(bottom.green, bottom.alpha, top.green, top.alpha, multiply_channel(bottom.green, top.green));
        blue = color_composite(bottom.blue, bottom.alpha, top.blue, top.alpha, multiply_channel(bottom.blue, top.blue));


        return [red, green, blue, union(bottom.alpha, top.alpha)];
    end


    def darken_channel(cb, cs)
        return [cb, cs].min
    end
    #DARKEN 
    def darken(top, bottom)
        assert_type top, :Color
        assert_type bottom, :Color

        red = color_composite(bottom.red, bottom.alpha, top.red, top.alpha,     darken_channel(bottom.red, top.red));
        green = color_composite(bottom.green, bottom.alpha, top.green, top.alpha, darken_channel(bottom.green, top.green));
        blue = color_composite(bottom.blue, bottom.alpha, top.blue, top.alpha, darken_channel(bottom.blue, top.blue));


        return [red, green, blue, union(bottom.alpha, top.alpha)];
    end
end
```

Here's what I'd like to do:

- Have **one function** to process the different channels, and take the blend mode as a parameter. eg. blend(top, bottom, 'multiply')
- Be able to **iterate** though the three channels to minimize duplication

If you can just point me in the right direction that would be greatly appriciated!

**EDIT**

I'd like to iterate over the colors like this:

```
color = []
for (red,green,blue) as channel
    color << color_composit(bottom.channel, bottom.alpha, top.channel, top.alpha, blendmode(bottom.channel, top.channel))
```

Also can the code you replied with be automated even more so I don't need to define a darken function that runs darken_channel on each channel, but just call the blend function and pass "darken" as a parameter, and then it appends "_channel" by itself? Can I just append a string?

Comment: Could you write some pseudocode to show how you would like to iterate though channels?

Answer (score 0):

This is your code slightly changed:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def union(b, s)
    b + s - (b * s)
  end

  def multiply(top, bottom)
    assert_type top, :Color
    assert_type bottom, :Color

    blend do |first_color, second_color|
      multiply_channel(first_color, second_color)
    end
  end

  def multiply_channel(cb, cs)
    cb * cs / 255
  end

  def darken(top, bottom)
    assert_type top, :Color
    assert_type bottom, :Color

    blend(bottom, top) do |first_color, second_color|
      darken_channel(first_color, second_color)
    end
  end

  def blend(channel_one, channel_two, &block)
    red = color_composite(channel_one.red, channel_one.alpha, channel_two.red, channel_two.alpha, block.call(channel_one.red, channel_two.red));
    green = color_composite(channel_one.green, channel_one.alpha, channel_two.green, channel_two.alpha, block.call(channel_one.green, channel_two.green));
    blue = color_composite(channel_one.blue, channel_one.alpha, channel_two.blue, channel_two.alpha, block.call(channel_one.blue, channel_two.blue));

    return [red, green, blue, union(channel_one.alpha, channel_two.alpha)];
  end

  def darken_channel(cb, cs)
    [cb, cs].min
  end

  def color_composite(cb, ab, cs, as, fnc)
    ((1 - as) * ab * cb) + ((1- ab) * as * cs) + (ab * as * fnc)
  end

end
```

Now, blend method has two arguments:

```
channel_one, channel_two
```

and accepts block. 
blend passed two block two parameters here and two other places:

```
block.call(channel_one.red, channel_two.red)
```

call executes block, its parameters are passed to block:

```
blend do |first_color, second_color|
  multiply_channel(first_color, second_color)
end
```

so `first_color` become `channel_one.red` and `second_color` become `channel_two.red`.
This block is called on each block.call.

Hope this help.